# Iterating over references to variables in Python

Tags: python, regex, foreach

I have an object called Song, which is defined as:

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = None
        self.songauthor = None
        self.textauthor = None
        self.categories = None
```

Inside this class I have a method that parses a run-time property of that object, "metadata", which is basically just a text file with some formatted text that I parse with regular expressions. During this process, I have come up with the following code that I am pretty certain can be simplified to a loop.

```
re_title = re.compile("^title:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
re_textauthor = re.compile("^textauthor:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
re_songauthor = re.compile("^songauthor:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
re_categories = re.compile("^categories:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)

#
# it must be possible to simplify the below code to a loop...
#
tmp = re_title.findall(self.metadata)
self.title = tmp[0] if len(tmp) > 0 else None

tmp = re_textauthor.findall(self.metadata)
self.textauthor = tmp[0] if len(tmp) > 0 else None

tmp = re_songauthor.findall(self.metadata)
self.songauthor = tmp[0] if len(tmp) > 0 else None

tmp = re_categories.findall(self.metadata)
self.categories = tmp[0] if len(tmp) > 0 else None
```

I'm guessing this can be done by encapsulating a reference to the property (e.g. self.title) and the corresponding regular expression (re_title) in a datatype (possibly tuple), and then iterate over a list of these data types.

I have a tried using a tuple as such:

```
for x in ((self.title, re_title),
      (self.textauthor, re_textauthor),
      (self.songauthor, re_songauthor),
      (self.categories, re_categories)):
    data = x[1].findall(self.metadata)
    x[0] = data[0] if len(data) > 0 else None
```

This failed horribly as I cannot modify a tuple in run-time. Can anyone provide a suggestion as to how I can pull this off?

Comment: Why are you using `findall` if you're only interested in the first match?

Comment: @MarkRansom Laziness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The big one is that `x[0]` is not a reference to `self.title`, it's a reference to *the value of* `self.title`. In other words, you're just copying the existing title into a tuple, then replacing that title in the tuple with a different one, which has no effect on the existing title.

The smaller one is that you can't replace elements in a tuple. You could fix that trivially by using a list instead of a tuple, but you're still going to have the big problem.

So, how do you create references to variables in Python? You can't. You need to think of a way to reorganize things. For example, maybe you can access these things by name, instead of by reference. Instead of four separate variables, store a dictionary of four variables in a single dictionary:

```
res = {
    'title': re.compile("^title:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE),
    'textauthor': re.compile("^textauthor:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
    'songauthor': re.compile("^songauthor:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
    'categories': re.compile("^categories:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
}

class Song(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {}

    def parsify(self, text):
        for thing in ('title', 'textauthor', 'songauthor', 'categories'):
            data = res[thing].findall(self.metadata)
            self.properties[thing] = data[0] if len(data) > 0 else None
```

You could also use `for thing in res:` there, because that will iterate over all the keys (in arbitrary order, but you probably don't care about the order).

If you really need to have `self.title`, you've run into a common problem. Usually, there's a clear distinction between data—which should be referred to by runtime strings—and attributes—which should not. But sometimes, there isn't. So you have to bridge between them in some way. You can create four `@property` fields that `return self.properties['title']`, or you can use `setattr(self, thing, …)` instead of `self.properties[thing]`, or various other possibilities. Which one is best comes down to whether they're more data-like or more attribute-like.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for both proposing a solution and also for pointing out something about Python that I suspected but was not fully aware of (create references for variables).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning to the tuple, update the class members directly:

```
all_res = {'title':re_title,
           'textauthor': re_textauthor,
           'songauthor': re_song_author,
           'categories': re_categories}

for k, v in all_res.iteritems():
    tmp = v.findall(self.metadata)
    if tmp:
        setattr(self, k, tmp[0])
    else:
        setattr(self, k, None)
```

If you only care about the first match, you don't need to use `findall`.

Answer (score 1):

abarnert's answer has given a good explanation of what is going wrong with your code, but I wanted to offer up an alternative solution. Rather than using a loop to assign each variable, try creating an iterable of the different values from the parsed file, then use a single unpacking-assignment to get them into the various variables.

Here's a two-statement solution using a list comprehension, which is made just a bit tricky by the fact that you need to reference the result of `findall` twice in `if`/`else` expression (thus the nested generator expression):

```
vals = [x[0] if len(x) > 0 else None for x in (regex.findall(self.metadata) for regex in
                                               [re_title, re_textauthor,
                                                re_songauthor, re_categories])]
self.title, self.textauthor, self.songauthor, self.categories = vals
```

You can probably simplify things a little bit in the first part of the list comprehension. To start with, you can just test `if x` rather than `if len(x) > 0`. Or, if you're not too attached to using `findall`, you could use `search` instead, then just use `x and x.group(0)` instead of the whole `if`/`else` bit. The `search` method returns `None` if no match was found, so the short-circuiting behavior of the `and` operator will do exactly what we want.

Comment: I think it would be more readable to turn the first line into two lines: Store the generator in `finds = (regex.findall…)`, then `vals = [x[0] if x else None for x in finds]`. (And it makes the code one line shorter while still staying well within 80 columns, too, so there's no real cost.) But +1 anyway; there's not that much repetition here, and it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

An example would be to use a dictionary like this:

```
things = {}

for x in ((self.title, re_title),
  (self.textauthor, re_textauthor),
  (self.songauthor, re_songauthor),
  (self.categories, re_categories)):
    if len(x[1].findall(self.metadata):
        things[x[0]] = x[1].findall(self.metadata)[1]
    else:
        things[x[0]] = None
```

Could this be a possible solution?

Comment: That isn't going to work. You're making a dictionary mapping the previous value of `self.title` to the found title, etc. Since the initial values of all those attributes are `None`, you end up with just a dictionary mapping `None` to the found category.